# How to search for a sentence instead of single word from a dictionary file in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program in c, that translates English sentences into spanish ones. The code must accept a txt file that contains the translations separated by commas like this

[image]

This is the current code i have but i dont know how to search by sentences instead of words. The code is supposed to take an input of an english sentence and output that sentence in spanish. for example (input) : Where is my english book (output): Donde esta mi ingles libro

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// creating global variables
#define MAXWORDS 50
#define LENGTH 30

// function to translate a word from english to spanish
void translate(char eng[][LENGTH], char spa[][LENGTH], int n, char *word)
{
    // check if the word exists in the english dictionary
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        // if the ith word matches
        if (strcmpi(eng[i], word) == 0)
        {
            // print the ith word from spanish dictionary and return
            printf("%s translates as '%s' in Spanish\n\n", word, spa[i]);
            return;
        }
    }
    // if the word was not found till now, then it doesnt exist in the dictionary
    printf("word: %s not found in dictionary\n\n", word);
}

// driver function
int main()
{
    // create 2 2D char arrays for the english and spanish words
    char eng[MAXWORDS][LENGTH], spa[MAXWORDS][LENGTH];

    // create a file pointer to read the file
    FILE *fptr = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
    // check if the file opened successfully
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("File could not be opened!");
        printf("Exiting...");
        exit(1);
    }

    int n = 0;
    // start reading the file
    while (fscanf(fptr, "%30[^,],%s\n", eng[n], spa[n]) != EOF && n < MAXWORDS)
    {
        n++;
    }
    // close the file pointer
    fclose(fptr);

    char ch = 'y', newline;
    do
    {
        char word[LENGTH];
        // prompt the user for a word to translate
        printf("Enter a word to translate to spanish: ");
        scanf("%s", word);
        // call translate()
        translate(eng, spa, n, word);

        // ask the user if they wish to translate another word
        printf("Do you want to translate another word? (Y/N): ");
        scanf("%c%c", &newline, &ch);

    } while (ch == 'Y' || ch == 'y');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `fgets` to get the whole sentence. Then use `strtok` to break that up into words and call `translate` for each of the words.

Comment: @kaylum I'm a newbie at this, would you mind providing an example on how this is done?

Comment: As a newbie it is even more important that you attempt to do it yourself. I have already pointed you to the functions and approach to use. Read up on those functions, search for examples and attempt to code as much of it as you can first.

Comment: @kaylum im getting stuck in an endless loop while asking the user if they want to search for another word `

Comment: Why? Do basic debugging by running the program in a debugger to find out why. Where is it stuck in a loop and what variable(s) are incorrect leading to that happening? Are you entering a while sentence or one word at a time?

Comment: Read on [Trie Data-Structure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). It improves your searching. Load your translations on to a `trie`; translate word by word. Languages come with nuisances, meaning of a sentence is often lost in translations. It's beyond the scope of your problem.